# set width and height of components programmatically

Tags: android

Application developed in Android 2.3.3

I am developing a calculator application.

Question 1 :::
I have around 16 buttons. Is there a way where in I can set the width and height of all the buttons using a loop (or) without it. I want all the buttons to be uniform.

Question 2 :::
What do you think of this practice? Good or Bad? Please explain why?
Let's say I have 4 buttons in each row. If I get the width and height of the screen programmatically and then divide (width/4) and add the margin for each button and then set the width (width/4 + margin) of the buttons respectively, will that somehow solve the problem of displaying in screens with different sizes?

Comment: What do you do ? can we have code please ?

Comment: @NiravRanpara ::: It's just a simple calculator. All i want is to get the width and height of all the buttons uniformly and also they should scale equally, for all screens.

Comment: If we have some code , then its good to do .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best way to equally provide the width or height of views according to device width and height, is to use weight property, lets take an example, we have a linear layout, with four buttons, of equal width:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal">
     <Button android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="button1"/>
     <Button android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="button2"/>
     <Button android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="button3"/>
     <Button android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="button4"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

However, if you still want to provide layout width and height at runtime, you can use `setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(100, 100));` method.

Comment: Thanks for the info. If i use the weight property on all the 4 buttons, will they divide the available space equally between them?

Comment: yes, actually thats the purpose of weight, but remember, provide width 0dip of the views of layout you want to provide weight.

Comment: Ok.. Can you tell me what 0dip does?

Comment: It tells, the weight is to be applied by width, not height.

Comment: Ok.. Will give it a try and will accept your answer. Thanks for your time.

Comment: yes, sure, and one more thing, if you want to divide height too, as I assume from your question, than take an LinearLayout for all the Buttons with orientation vertical, width and height to match parent, and have four child linear layouts of this layouts, with layout height=0dip, and weight 1 each, and width=fill_parent, and each linearlayout will be same like my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Steps to set the width and height of view at run time**

**First** get layout params using view.getLayoutParams().

**Second** then set the height and width value then last set the layout params of view.

```
LayoutParams params = null;
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
params = button.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 70;
params.width = 70;
button .setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Things to remember:**

- set the android:layout_width of the children to "0dp"
- set the android:weightSum of the parent (edit: as Jason Moore noticed, this attribute is optional, because by default it is set to the children's layout_weight sum)
- set the android:layout_weight of each child proportionally (e.g. weightSum="5", three children: layout_weight="1", layout_weight="3", layout_weight="1")

Example:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="1" />

 <Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="1" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="1" />

 <Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="1" />

  <Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info. I already accepted other's answer. Very kind of you. Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: @VamsiChalla : Not a problem. But I think my ans is useful :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by setting up your elements in the XML and then modifying the height and width in the Java code:

```
Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);    
LayoutParams layoutParams = btn1.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.width(int width);
layoutParams.height(int height);
btn1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

**Or** you could just use Java to create the whole layout:

```
for(int x = 0; x<3; x++){
    for(int y=0; y<3; y++){
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        ... //Set layoutParams and button info for each button.
    }    
}
```

**Or** one more option would be to use a linearLayout and use element weights.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/register"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    weight=".3" />
```

Answer (score -2):

Try This code

```
LayoutParams params = null;
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
params = button .getLayoutParams();
params.height = 100;
params.width = 100;
button .setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: you just copied from the answer above!